# Creating an array of pictures and creating avatars at the side of table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

have only been learning objective C for a couple of days now and currently baffled by tables/ UITableView etc.. I've created a table and it lists 6 names I've read up how to set the avatar (image to the left of the text) to 1 picture however I have been playing about trying to set each individual image using an array. Heres what I have, no issues just the simulator crashes constantly? Thanks in advance.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SImple_TableViewController : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray * listData;
    NSArray* listPics;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *listData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray* listPics;

@end



#import "SImple_TableViewController.h"

@implementation SImple_TableViewController

@synthesize listData, listPics;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [listData release];
    [listPics release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bradley", @"Glen",@"Alan",@"Sean",@"Mark",@"Luke",@"Jack", nil];
   NSArray *pics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ME.jpg",@"Sean.jpg",@"Glenn.jpg",@"Mark.jpg",@"Luke.jpg",@"Jack.jpg",@"Alan.jpg", nil];

    self.listData = array;
   // self.listPics = pics;

    [array release];
    [pics release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.listData = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
#pragma mark - 

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.listData count];
    return [self.listPics count];
}

    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
    { static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SImpleTableIdentifier";


        UITableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]autorelease];

        }



        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
        return cell;


        UIImage*image = [UIImage imageNamed: listPics];
        cell.imageView.image = [listPics objectAtIndex:row];
        return cell;


}


@end
```

Comment: -1 seriously? you're going to copy and paste your class in here and expect us to debug it for you? what have you tried? what are the errors you're getting? does the crash produce a backtrace? have you tried debugging this yourself?

Comment: This isn't too much code and not a complicated code either. Stackoverflow is here to help people, if you aren't willing to, don't answer, but others may. I'm just saying...

Comment: @David Schiefer: Agreed. We should especially be patient with new users who may not be aware of standard practices on SO. @Bradley, You can update your question with more information and/or respond to answers with comments if you aren't getting the help you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an important thing to remember: no code that occurs after `return` will ever be reached. FOr example:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.listData count]; // METHOD RETURNS HERE
    return [self.listPics count]; // THIS LINE IS NEVER REACHED
}
```

You can only `return` once.

This same error occurs in your method `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

---

Here's another problem that I see. This line:

```
NSArray *pics = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ME.jpg",@"Sean.jpg",@"Glenn.jpg",@"Mark.jpg",@"Luke.jpg",@"Jack.jpg",@"Alan.jpg", nil];
```

creates an array of `NSString` objects. If you wish to put `UIImages` into an array, then in place of `@"ME.jpg"`, you should have `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ME.jpg"]`. Make sure to add the image, with the **exact same name** (case sensitive) to the project.